# Finite satisfiability does not imply consistency

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

A set $\Gamma$ of propositional logic formulae over $(P, C)$ is said to be finitely satisfiable if and only if every finite subset $\Gamma_{0} \subset_{\text{fin}} \Gamma$ of $\Gamma$ is satisfiable.

Let $\Gamma$ be a set of propositional logic formulae over $(P, C)$. $\Gamma$ is said to be $P$-consistent if for every proposition $p \in P$, either $p \not\in \Gamma$ or $\neg p \not\in \Gamma$.

The above are definitions of finite satisfiabiity and P-consistency. The given question is to come up with counterexample for finite $\Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is finitely satisfiable but not P-consistent.

According to the above definition, the only case where $\Gamma$ is not P-consistent is when there exists some $p \in P$ such that $p \in P$ and $\neg p \in P$, and that immediately implies that $\Gamma$ is not finitely satisfiable. How is it possible to consider the above counterexample? Am I missing something here?

Thanks!!

Comment: Agreed... by [Compactness](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/compactness-theorem) a set of formulas is satisfiable iff every finite subset is satisfiable.

Comment: In "every finite subset $\Gamma_0 \subset_{\text{fin}} \Gamma$", is the intention that $\subset$ means proper subset (i.e. $\Gamma \subset \Gamma$ would be false)? If it is, then $\Gamma = \{p, \neg p\}$ technically works, assuming that both $p$ and $\neg p$ are satisfiable; $\{p, \neg p\}$ isn't a proper subset and therefore wouldn't be a valid choice for $\Gamma_0$, so the fact that it's not satisfiable doesn't matter. (Although if that is the idea, then this is just a bad definition). If it's not that, then I agree there are clearly no counterexamples.

Comment: The other obvious thought is that the question might have been asked the wrong way around, since there *are* examples of $\Gamma$ being P-consistent but not finitely satisfiable.

Comment: I think the question given is a bit errornous. Thanks for the reply everyone!